# Iptables management with ansible in huge environment

Tags: iptables, ansible

What is the best way to manage iptables from one point and have the ability to edit something on local server.

We need to add some rules centralized on all servers, but we have specific servers with specific requirements which should have their own set of rules.

I thought about bash script with multiple include which is managed centralized with ansible and includes managed on local server. Is it good approach? Or maybe there is something better?

We can't create yml2 templates for ansible because there is too much difference between specific hosts.

Please provide examples of centralized management of iptables.

Answer (score 25):

### ufw

`Ansible` has a [`ufw` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ufw_module.html) in order to handle firewall rules. In `roles/common/tasks/main.yml`, which is included in all my servers, I have (among other things):

```
- name: Install ufw
  apt: name=ufw
- name: Allow ssh through firewall
  ufw: proto=tcp port=22 rule=allow
- name: Set ufw policy
  ufw: state=enabled direction=incoming policy=deny
```

**Edit**: It is necessary to allow ssh before setting default policy to "deny" (originally it was opposite above), otherwise you may be locked out in between the two steps.

Then, in each role, I have additional firewall rules for that role. For example, in `roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml`, I have (among other things) this:

```
- name: Allow nginx firewall
  ufw: proto=tcp port=80 rule=allow
- name: Allow nginx ssl firewall
  ufw: proto=tcp port=443 rule=allow
```

So all my nginx servers have ports 80 and 443 opened.

This way you can build whatever common configuration you want and add additional rules in more specific roles.

### ferm

If you have rules which `ufw` cannot handle, one solution I think would work nicely is `ferm`; it can do almost anything, and you can configure it to read rules from directories such as `/etc/ferm/input.d/`, `/etc/ferm/output.d/`, `/etc/ferm/forward.d/`, etc. You could make your `common` role prepare the essential `ferm` configuration and then have other roles drop files in these directories.

### plain iptables

Your requirement to have `ansible` specify rules in addition to rules specified in another way is unusual and apparently defies most of the point for using `ansible`. Unfortunately I don't see any way to do it other than with plain `iptables`, which would be quite ugly. Here is an example of opening up port 80 in `roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml` (untested):

```
- name: Check if port 80 is allowed
  shell: iptables -L | grep -q "Allow http" && echo -n yes || echo -n no
  register: check_allow_http
  changed_when: no
  always_run: yes

- name: Allow port 80
  command: >
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80
    -m comment --comment "Allow http" -j ACCEPT
  when: check_allow_http.stdout == "no"
  notify:
  - Save iptables
```

where `Save iptables` is a handler that executes `iptables-save`. All the above is quite tedious to write, but it might be appropriate, especially if you have only a few rules to manage with `ansible`.

Comment: If i remember correctly with this approach i can't use ipset and create something very specific. We are using module owner in iptables.

For example we have iptables -m owner --uid 0 -j ACCEPT. I can't use this module with ufw in ansible and can't edit something without ansible on local server.

Comment: Indeed, `ufw` apparently can't handle your needs; but what do you mean when you say you "can't edit something without ansible on local server"?

Comment: Is there another solution? I stuck with this case, hard to solve.

In general i mean that i need to only add NEW rules with ansible without breaking existing one. Do not store all configuration on server with ansible. English not my native language, so i hope i made myself clear:)

Comment: Updated my answer with some alternatives.

Comment: Thank you veru much i will look into this, especially ferm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Antonios. I'm curious what `Save iptables` does...  I thought the command was enough.

Comment: +1 for ferm, there is even a [debops.ferm](http://docs.debops.org/en/latest/ansible/roles/debops.ferm.html) package - you can use it as inspiration .

Comment: I created a role to manage iptables rules: https://github.com/mikegleasonjr/ansible-role-firewall

Answer (score 12):

## lineinfile

If you want to manage rules in your iptables configuration without overwriting existing rules or centrally managing iptables in a template, use Ansible's lineinfile module:

```
- name: ensure iptables allows established and related traffic
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables
    state=present 
    regexp="^.*INPUT.*ESTABLISHED,RELATED.*ACCEPT" 
    insertafter="^:OUTPUT " line="-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" 
    backup=yes
  notify: restart iptables


- name: ensure iptables is configured to allow ssh traffic (port 22/tcp)
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables 
    state=present 
    regexp="^.*INPUT.*tcp.*22.*ACCEPT" 
    insertafter="^.*INPUT.*ESTABLISHED,RELATED.*ACCEPT" line="-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT" 
    backup=yes
  notify: restart iptables
```

Here's the "restart iptables" handler:

```
- name: restart iptables
  service: name=iptables state=restarted
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a role to manage iptables rules with the following features:

- Support virtually all iptables rules
- Allow granular rules addition/overriding for specific hosts
- Easily inject variables in the rules
- Allow rules ordering
- Simplicity
- Persistence (reload the rules at boot)

Check out mikegleasonjr.firewall on [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/5878) or on [github](https://github.com/mikegleasonjr/ansible-role-firewall)

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a special module for this called [iptables_raw](https://github.com/Nordeus/ansible_iptables_raw) which allows us to easily manage iptables. Everything is explained in this [blog post](http://blog.nordeus.com/dev-ops/managing-iptables-with-ansible-the-easy-way.htm). Here is an example of how to use the module:

```
# Allow all IPv4 traffic coming in on port 80
- iptables_raw:
    name=allow_tcp_80
    rules='-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT'

# Delete the above rule
- iptables_raw:
    name=allow_tcp_80
    state=absent
```

Comment: we have solved this issue with this script: https://github.com/SmilingNavern/iptables.

Comment: But there is no proper documentation currently. I can explain how it works and post as answer later.